# Xcode 3.2.6 good for iPhone with iOS 5 beta 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

If I upgrade my iPhone 4 to iOS 5 beta 6, can I still use it as a debug device if my Xcode is 3.2.6 on Snow Leopard?

Comment: No, you need Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you need to have xcode 4.2 beta in order to run the app on your iphone. But if you can get ios 5 then you should be able to get xcode 4.2 (because i assume that you are a registered developer?).

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can still develop with 3.2.6 and the 4.3 SDK and run on iOS 5.

You may get the following error message, but it still seems possible to make it work:

The version of iOS on  does not match any of the
versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of
the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed
below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is
available here.

I have both 3.2.6 and 4.2 GM installed.  What worked for me was to close down 3.2.6, start up 4.2. Once 4.2 recognized the device correctly, I shut it down and restarted 3.2.6 and all worked.

I had been running successfully with another device using the GM seed, which caused me to proceed.

Exact sequence of events (IIRC):
- plug in upgraded iPhone to 3.2.6, comes up with the grey circle and the message
- right click 'add to provisioning portal' - came up yellow
- shut down xcode 3.2.6
- started up xcode 4.2
- waited until it turned green
- shut down 4.2 and restarted 3.2.6